# How to add non key attribute to an existing dynamodb table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have a table with HASH and RANGE key as my composite primary key (personalId and Name), and an LSI with partition and sort key (personalId and Contact). I want to update the table to add a new Age as nonkey attribute but i am getting error as below

An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the UpdateItem operation: Invalid UpdateExpression: An expression attribute name used in the document path is not defined; attribute name: #Age

```
        response = table.update_item(
            Key={"presonal-id": id, "name": name},
            UpdateExpression="SET #PersonAge=:age",
            ExpressionAttributeNames={"#PersonAge": "Age"},
            ExpressionAttributeValues={":age": person_age},
        )
```

Expected Age attribute to be add to the existing table having attributes personal-id, name and contact